# Como resolver o problema "O método principal não foi encontrado" em uma classe em Java?

Tags: java, método

Criei este ArrayList e no momento da execução aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Erro: O método principal não foi encontrado na classe
>   DeclaracaoArray.Declaracao_Array; defina o método principal como:
>   public static void main(String[] args)

Lendo a mensagem, e com a ajuda de colegas aqui do SOPT, percebe-se que em meu código falta o método principal, minha dúvida é Onde coloco este método? Ja tentei de diversas formas, porém sem sucesso.

Como ficaria o meu código com este novo método?

```
package DeclaracaoArray;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Declaracao_Array {

    public String sorteia (){

            List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

            lista.add ( "Alice" );
            lista.add ( "Bruno" );
            lista.add ( "Carlos");
            lista.add ( "Daniel");

           Collections.shuffle ( lista );   

           return lista.get(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Essa é a sua classe principal? Se sim, como a mensagem de erro já diz, falta o `void main` nela,

Comment: Você está tentando rodar essa classe apenas? Sem o Método main ela nao vai rodar mesmo. Adicione o metodo <code>'public static void main(String args[]){}'</code> e execute novamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse código pode ir em qualquer lugar dentro da sua classe, por exemplo assim:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Declaracao_Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Declaracao_Array d = new Declaracao_Array();
        System.out.println(d.sorteia());
    }

    public String sorteia (){
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

        lista.add ( "Alice" );
        lista.add ( "Bruno" );
        lista.add ( "Carlos");
        lista.add ( "Daniel");

        Collections.shuffle ( lista );   

        return lista.get(0);
    }
}
```

Para o caso acima eu criei um objeto do tipo da própria classe para que fosse possível chamar o método `sorteia()` caso contrário ele não seria acessível, mas você ainda tem a opção de fazer de outro jeito definindo o método como estático e acessá-lo direto do método main sem a necessidade de instanciar um objeto. Assim:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Declaracao_Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sorteia());
    }

    public static String sorteia (){
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

        lista.add ( "Alice" );
        lista.add ( "Bruno" );
        lista.add ( "Carlos");
        lista.add ( "Daniel");

        Collections.shuffle ( lista );   

        return lista.get(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa ter um método com a seguinte assinatura

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

esse será o ponto de entrada da sua aplicação. Ele será o primeiro método a ser executado e por isso é obrigatório.

Aplicando ao seu código, ficaria algo como:

```
package DeclaracaoArray;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Declaracao_Array {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        sorteia();
    }       

    public static String sorteia (){

        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

        lista.add ( "Alice" );
        lista.add ( "Bruno" );
        lista.add ( "Carlos");
        lista.add ( "Daniel");
        Collections.shuffle ( lista );   

        return lista.get(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Exemplo:

```
public class Declaracao_Array {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

     }

     public static void metodo(){

     }

}
```

Comment: Valeu, corrigi a resposta.